# PHP header(Location:'index.php') and javascript not being executed

Tags: javascript, php, header, location

My problem is, when the user logout. The login page is being called and the index page is showing but the url is saying

```
  https://mysite/logout.php
```

instead of

```
   https://mysite/index.php
```

which means my javascript files included in the index.php ain't being loaded, so you cant log in again without refreshing the page manually.

Link in home.php the page you reach after login

```
 <p class="mc-top-margin-1-5"><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></p>
```

I have the following logout page (logout.php)

```
   <?php

     session_start();
     require_once 'php/class/class.user.php';
     $user = new USER();

     if(!$user->is_logged_in())
       {
          $user->redirect('index.php');
          exit;
       }

     if($user->is_logged_in()!="")
       {
         $user->logout();
         $user->redirect('index.php');
         exit;
       }
    ?>
```

my user functions as follow (class.user.php)

```
    public function is_logged_in()
{
    if(isset($_SESSION['userSession']))
    {

        return true;
    }
}

public function redirect($url)
{
    header("Location: $url");


}

public function logout()
{
    session_destroy();


}
```

what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so i ended up with a not very nice solution:

I changed the link in home.php

```
    `<p class="mc-top-margin-1-5"><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></p>  `
```

To a button

```
    <button id="btn-logout">Logout</button>
```

and added its functionality in a jquery function

```
   $(function(){

   $("#btn-logout").bind('click', function () {

    window.location.href = "http://example.com/logout.php";
      })
   });
```

my logout.php ended up looking like

```
  <?php
    session_start();
    unset($_SESSION['user_session']);
    session_destroy();
  ?>
 <html>
 <head>
 <script>
    window.location.href = "https://example.com/index.php";
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

So going from refresh page in php using header. I ended up with js and jquery. Its not a nice solution above, but it works!

Answer (score 0):

Your function `is_logged_in()` returns a boolean, TRUE, but you are checking the return value with:

```
 if($user->is_logged_in()!="")
```

That is, checking if it's an empty string.

Also, and more importantly, `is_logged_in()` doesn't return anything if the user is not logged in. That function should be something like:

```
    public function is_logged_in()
{
    if(isset($_SESSION['userSession']))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else { return false; }
```

}

And the check should be something like:

```
 if(!$user->is_logged_in())
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I added your code. I'm still not being redirected to the index.php. Its still stuck on the https://mysite/logout.php page

Comment: See if you have any whitespace or white lines before your code. "Header" only works if nothing has been sent to the browser yet.

Comment: But it do give me the index.php's userinterface but the browser says: https://mysite/login.php and mine js files aint fireing. So I guess the header works - alittle